# Laws given at locations

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

There were many divrei Torah that I read recently which addressed the question of mah inyan sh'mittah Etzel har Sinai, why does the Torah point out specifically that the concept and laws of the Sh'mittah years were given at Mt. Sinai.

Are there instances of other laws which are recorded as having been given at other places, for which a parallel question is asked?

Comment: Maybe שם שם לו חק ומשפט

Comment: ויאמר יהוה אל משה ואל אהרן בארץ מצרים לאמר החדש הזה...

Comment: וידבר יהוה אל-משה במדבר סיני, באהל מועד:  באחד לחדש השני בשנה השנית, לצאתם מארץ מצרים--לאמר.

Comment: וידבר יהוה אל-משה, במדבר סיני לאמר. פקד את-בני לוי

Comment: וידבר משה ואלעזר הכהן, אתם--בערבת מואב:  על-ירדן ירחו, לאמר

Comment: וידבר יהוה אל-משה, בערבת מואב, על-ירדן ירחו, לאמר.

Comment: Mt Sinai means Matan Torah in general, not the specific coordinates of it. Presumably everything was transmitted at M"S. So are you trying to draw a similarity to Marah, for example, where Kibud Av was given - why at Marah?

Comment: @AlBerko Yes -- if everything was given at Sinai, but the text specifies Sh'mittah, the commentators ask why. Do they ask why other things were specified connected to other locations. Rosh Chodesh and Egypt makes some measure of sense. But what about in other cases?

Comment: First, you assume (arguably) that Torah was given Parshiot Parshiot, which Midrash of "Shmita" clearly contradicts. Second, even so, you link the Parshiot to a place, not the time, for example, Shmitah to Har Sinai, not to Matan Torah. I would say, Rosh Chodesh wasn't given specifically in Egypt, it was given before the Exodus, which happened to be in Egypt. Or Arvos Moav before entering the Land of Israel, not specifically there.

Comment: @AlBerko The wording in both cases is identical: by Shmittah it says ויאמר ה אל משה בהר ביני לאמר, and by Rosh Chodesh it says ויאמר ה אל משה ואל אהרן בארץ מצרים לאמר. On what basis do you say there’s something inherently connecting Shmittah to Har Sinai, but not Rosh Chodesh to Mitzraim?